# Is there an equivalent of Python's list and append feature in Matlab?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

This is more of a Matlab programming question than it is a math question.

I'd like to run gradient descent multiple on different learning rates. I have a set of learning rates

```
alpha = [0.3, 0.1, 0.03, 0.01, 0.003, 0.001];
```

and each time I run gradient descent, I get a vector `J_vals` as output. However, I don't know Matlab well enough to know how to implement this besides doing something like:

```
[theta, J_vals] = gradientDescent(...., alpha(1),...);
J1 = J_vals;
[theta, J_vals] = gradientDescent(...., alpha(2),...);
J2 = J_vals;
```

and so on.

I thought about using a for loop, but then I don't know how I would deal with the `J_vals`'s (not sure how to apply the for loop to `J1`, `J2`, and so on). Perhaps it would look something like this:

```
for i = len(alpha)
     [theta, J_vals] = gradientDescent(..., alpha(i),...);
     J(i) = J_vals;
end
```

Then I would have a vector of vectors.

In Python, I would just run a for loop and append each new result to the end of a list. How do I implement something like this in Matlab? Or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works just fine as long as you add a `:` for the row subscript (assuming `J_vals` is a column vector):

```
for i = len(alpha)
     [theta, J_vals] = gradientDescent(..., alpha(i),...);
     J(:, i) = J_vals;
  %//  ^... all rows, column 'i'
end
```

You could even put that as the return value:

```
for i = len(alpha)
     [theta, J(:, i)] = gradientDescent(..., alpha(i),...);
     %//       ^... add returned value directly to our list
end
```

Both of these methods allow you to preallocate your matrix for a potential speed gain.

If you want to build your list as you go, you can use the method in @dpmcmlxxvi's answer, or you can use the special subscript `end`. Neither of these methods are compatible with preallocation, though.

```
for i = len(alpha)
     [theta, J(:, end+1)] = gradientDescent(..., alpha(i),...);
     %//          ^... add new vector after the current end of list
end
```

I would also like to suggest you not use `i` as a variable name in Matlab. I know it's natural for other languages, but in Matlab it overwrites the built-in imaginary constant `i`.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14790765/1377097

Comment: J_vals is a column vector. does that change your response?

Comment: @AlanH You only need to swap the subscripts. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many loops you are going have and the size of the `J_vals` (or at least a reasonable upper bound) I would suggest pre-allocating the size of the container array

```
J = zeros(n,1);
```

then on each loop insert the new values

```
J(start:start+n) = J_vals
```

That way you don't reallocate memory. If you don't know, you can append the values to the array. For example,

```
J = []; % initialize
for i = len(alpha)
     [theta, J_vals] = gradientDescent(..., alpha(i),...);
    J = [J; J_vals]; % Append column row
end
```

but this is re-allocating the size of the array every loop. If it's not too many loops then it should be ok.

Comment: In python, lists can take elements of any type, but does apply in Matlab's arrays?

Comment: For different types use [**cell arrays**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

Answer (score 3):

Matlab's ["cell arrays"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) are kind of like lists in Python. They are similar in that you can put variable datatypes into them. Nobody seems to be too sure, but [most likely the cell array is implemented as an array of object pointers.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/156240/in-matlab-how-can-preallocating-cell-arrays-improve-performance) That means that it is still somewhat expensive to append to it (`cell_array{length(cell_array) + 1} = new_data`), but at least you are only appending a pointer instead of the entire column. You would still have to convert the cell array to a normal matrix afterward using [cell2mat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

The most idiomatic Matlab solution is to pre-allocate (as @dpmcmlxxvi suggested).

I think what you are describing is a really common use case, and it's unfortunate that Matlab requires such a verbose idiom for this. Also it's frustrating that the documentation is opaque on how cell arrays are implemented and whether it is expensive to append to a cell array.